# Why can't I select a pre-created schema in Oracle 18c XE when creating a new workspace in APEX?

Tags: oracle, connection, schema, oracle-apex, oracle-xe

i have just started to work with oracle and apex, so I don't know my way around yet.
I have installed oracle 18c xe and connected it to the sql developer. Then I have installed apex 19.1 and successfully connected to it via localhost and the admin user. 
After that i after that i created a new schema in the database and grant them diferent privileges. Now I wanted to create a new workspace and use this pre-created schema but it is not displayed.
I've tried it a few times, but it doesn't work.

What could be the reason?

So far, i've tried to determine the current Application Express engine schema with `SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_OWNER FROM all_synonyms
WHERE SYNONYM_NAME = 'WWV_FLOW' and OWNER = 'PUBLIC'` but here i don't get a value. I saw this on the oracle manual https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/AEADM/managing-schemas.htm#AEADM232

The following steps on this page do not work either

Answer (score 0):

If you've created the schema and created the workspace (it's not clear if you've done that second part), you probably need to add the schema to the workspace. You can do that with [`APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.ADD_SCHEMA`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/AEAPI/ADD_SCHEMA-Procedure.htm#AEAPI250). Or you can log into the `INTERNAL` workspace in the Apex designer and add it there.